# Jquery runtime error: object expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

The Jquery script that controls my tabcontainer gives an "object expected" runtime error.
I honestly can't find the reason why:

```
$(document).ready(function() {



//When page loads...
 $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
 $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
 $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

 //On Click Event
 $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
  $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
  $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

  var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
  $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
  return false;
 });

});
```

Has it something to do with the stylesheet?

Comment: unless you provide more info about the error and where it's occuring your going to find it hard to get n answer. have you included the jQuery script file correctly. What about running the code in a stripped down html page that contains only the bare minimum elements to run?

Comment: have you linked to jquery.js?

Comment: Please post your markup, looks like one of your anchors points to a non-existent ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you want to remove you `var` from a selector

```
 activeTab.fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
```

If you are getting an error @ `$(document).ready(function() {` remember to include the jQuery script.

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Not sure about removing var. That wouldn't change anything. Including jQuery may help though.

Comment: Ah! it was the ><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> that I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your code works in this html page;

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    //When page loads...
     $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
     $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
     $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

     //On Click Event
     $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

      $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
      $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
      $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

      var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
      $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
      return false;
     });

    }); 

</script>   
</head>
<body>

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#one">Tab One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">Tab Two</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="one" class="tab_content">Tab One Content</div>
    <div id="two" class="tab_content">Tab Two Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

so it must be soemthing else other that the code you show?

Answer (score 1):

Editted as I was wrong first time :-)

Your problem is these lines:

```
var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //This will return a string value
$(activeTab).fadeIn();                             //Meaning this will fail
```

You need to change the selector for activeTab to get the .tab_content which you want to show.

I assume the href value is contained within the .tab_content somewhere.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, he has tabs above the content, like most tab strips work, the content is in separate divs, at least I assume so since this is how almost *all* tabs work.

Comment: nope, it still gives the error.
It also seems as the error occures at the

$(document).ready(function() { 

line... but I could be wrong

Comment: if your error occurs at the `$(document).ready(` line then my guess is you aren't correctly including jquery. make sure your urls are correct. I just put your code in a html test page with the code you show there and it works fine.

Comment: See the answer below concerning including jQuery.